# VEX prefixes encoding and SSE/AVX MOVUP(D/S) instructions

Tags: x86, x86-64, intel, cpu-architecture, avx

I'm trying to understand the VEX prefix encoding for the SSE/AVX instructions. So please bear with me if I ask something simple. I have the following related questions.

Let's take the [MOVUP(D/S)](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf) instruction (`0F 10`). If I follow the 2-byte VEX prefix encoding correctly:

[image]

The following two instruction encodings produce the same result:

```
db 0fh, 10h, 00000000b              ; movups      xmm0,xmmword ptr [rax]
db 0c5h, 11111000b, 10h, 00000000b  ; vmovups     xmm0,xmmword ptr [rax]
```

As these two:

```
db 066h, 0fh, 10h, 00000000b        ; movupd      xmm0,xmmword ptr [rax]
db 0c5h, 11111001b, 10h, 00000000b  ; vmovupd     xmm0,xmmword ptr [rax]
```

Thus my questions:

1. What does the first `v` stand for in those instructions? Is it just to denote the use of the `VEX` prefix?
2. Does it make any difference (with the exception of the length of the instructions) if I use or don't use the `VEX` prefix in the examples above?
3. I'm trying to understand [Intel's syntax](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf) in their documentation. Say, this screenshot:

[image]

In `VEX.128.0F.WIG` I can see that `.128` is the bit 2 (`L`) of the 2nd `VEX` byte. Then `.0F` is for a 3-byte `VEX` prefix, `m-mmmm` form to be `00001`, right? But what does the `WIG` part stand for?

4. Is `VEX` prefix recognized by the Intel CPUs only? How about AMD?
5. Lastly, what is the difference between `movups` and `movupd`? It seems like both of them simply move 16 bytes from the source memory:

[image]

into the `xmm` register:

[image]

and the "double" or "single" precision packing really doesn't make any difference.

Thanks for your patience with me.

Comment: AMD CPUs since Bulldozer have supported AVX (and thus VEX encodings).  See https://agner.org/optimize/ for more details about x86 microarchitectures.

Comment: `movups` vs. `movupd` makes no difference on any CPU made so far.  Some CPUs have domain-crossing latency for integer vs. FP (especially for reg-reg moves), but no CPUs have separate double/single domains.  Use `movups` because it's shorter.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thanks. Now, what does that `.WIG` abbreviation mean in the Intel docs. do you know?

Comment: W ignored, as opposed to the W bit being meaningful or being mandated as 0 or 1

Comment: @harold: haha. Oh, I get it. That was silly of me. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterCordes According to the Intel opt manual, on Skylake, the throughput of `MOVUPS xmm, xmm` is 0.25 while the throughput of `MOVUPD xmm, xmm` is 0.33. But the latency is the same. Perhaps, the throughput is also different when the source operand is in memory.

Comment: @HadiBrais: The manual is wrong.  Assuming mov-elimination works at all, throughput = 0.25 for both if even 1 of the 4 uops is eliminated on average.  (mov-elimination success rate is normally much higher).  `movups/d same,same` would defeat mov-elimination and give you 0.33 throughput.

Comment: @HadiBrais: see http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel00506E3_Skylake2_InstLatX64.txt experimental test results, for example.  The `(V)MOVUPS xmm, xmm` 0.34 throughput numbers must be for same,same.  They match the movupd numbers pretty much exactly.  There are also `movupd xmm1, xmm2` that show the expected 0.25c throughput and under-1-cycle latency.  (Their testing fails to measure it as zero because I guess they actually bottleneck on the front-end, instead of inserting it into a known-latency bottleneck.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yea looks like an error in the manual.

Comment: Yup, not exactly rare.  But fortunately between Agner Fog's experimental results + instlatx64, we can usually check Intel's numbers.  Or just ignore Intel's because they're wrong more often than Agner cross-checked by instlat, and only Agner Fog tells you which ports instructions run on, which is essential because real code rarely just repeats only the same instruction back-to-back (or in a simple loop).  Unfortunately Agner's tables have errors too, but they're often surprising enough to to make you double-check.  (e.g. 5 instead of 0.5).  (IACA is handy for uop->port stuff, e.g. for SKX.)

Comment: @HadiBrais: Hah. very interesting. Thanks for sharing, guys. I also just found out something new to me. I previously assumed that `vmovups xmm0, xmmword ptr [rax]` and `movups xmm0, xmmword ptr [rax]` were different only in their encodings (`vmovups` was using the VEX prefix, while `movups` was not.) But it seems like there's more to it, i.e. `vmovups` clears bits above bit 127 of the YMM0, ZMM0 registers, while `movups` does not. Is it something that I glossed over in the documentation?

Comment: There **is** a difference between the `VEX` encoded instruction and its legacy SSE encoded version. `VEX` encoded 128-bit instructions set the upper half of the 256-bit `ymm` vector (or the upper 3/4 of `zmm`...) to zero, avoiding partial register write stalls. In contrast, the legacy encoding leaves the upper part unchanged, causing severe slowdown when mixing AVX-256 code and SSE code on some microarchitectures.

Comment: @EOF: Thanks for that addition. Just from curiosity though, what's causing that stalling?

Comment: If you have the following sequence: `AVX256-op SSE-op AVX256-op` where `SSE-op` modifies part of the register written by the first `AVX256-op`, and the second `AVX256-op` *reads* that register as input, then it must see partial values of two previous instruction for one of its inputs. For an out-of-order machine, this is pretty nasty, since you have to track the dependencies and merge the two values into one. On early Intel AVX uarches, this can take on the order of a hundred cycles.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. What does the first v stand for in those instructions? Is it just to denote the use of the VEX prefix?

v stands for the AVX version of the instruction.

> 2. Does it make any difference (with the exception of the length of the instructions) if I use or don't use the VEX prefix in the examples above?

Yes, it does. If you use the VEX prefix, upper bits of the register are cleared. (e.g. if you use vmovups xmm0, the upper half ymm0 is cleared.

> 3. I'm trying to understand Intel's syntax in their documentation. [snip]. But what does the WIG part stand for?

"W" = width flag. "IG" = ignored.

From section "3.1.1.2 Opcode Column in the Instruction Summary Table (Instructions with VEX prefix)" in the manual,

"— WIG: can use C5H form (if not requiring VEX.mmmmm) or VEX.W value is ignored in the C4H form of VEX prefix."

"— If WIG is present, the instruction may be encoded using either the two-byte form or the three-byte form of VEX. When encoding the instruction using the three-byte form of VEX, the value of VEX.W is ignored."

> 4. Is VEX prefix recognized by the Intel CPUs only? How about AMD?

It is recognized by any CPU that supports AVX. Both Intel and AMD have supported it since ~2011 (Intel's Sandy Bridge and later, and AMD's Bulldozer and later)

> 5. Lastly, what is the difference between movups and movupd? It seems like both of them simply move 16 bytes from the source memory:

I believe that some processors may maintain flags on the contents of floating point SIMD registers; and using the wrong width/type may cause a stall in some situations.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. All of that was answered in the comments to my main question about 4 months ago.

Comment: Ah apologies; I didn't expand all of the original comments to see the answers directly to all of your questions. Hopefully having all of them explicitly answered here is useful though.

Comment: Yes. That is. Thank you.