# Does gcc flag -mavx2 affect code that doesn't employ AVX2 instructions?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, avx2

I have function `Foo` uses `AVX2` instruction like `_mm256_loadu_si256` from `avxintrin.h`, so I add flag `-mavx2` for gcc.

My CPU doesn't support `AVX2` actually, and I have functionality for instruction switch. E.g., if the CPU doesn't support AVX2 but does support SSE2, it will use the overloaded function of `Foo` that employs SSE2 instructions.

The code is well compiled.

But when it's running, the code that doesn't use `Foo` just corrupted, it's `std::deque` actually, gave error message `Illegal instruction occurred`.

Does gcc flag `-mavx2` affect code that doesn't employ `AVX2` instructions?

Comment: If you use flags like `-mavx2` you will tell the compiler that it is can use `avx2` instructions for its optimizations within the compilation units for which you use that flag, even if you don't explicitly use a function that requires avx.

Comment: @t.niese I don't want these instructions for optimizations. The only reason I use `-mavx2` is that I want to employ `AVX2` instructions `explicitly`.

Comment: You need to place all of the code that should utilize avx2 into distinct compilation units(s). And use `-mavx2` only for those.

Comment: Adding `-mavx2` or `-mavx` will even change the way scalar floating point math is encoded (and will not run on machines which don't support AVX). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51773399/vex-prefixes-encoding-and-sse-avx-movupd-s-instructions

Comment: @t.niese That sounds good.

Comment: @chtz These two flags are overkill to me. I only want to make use of some functions.

Comment: Here are the examples on how to perform manual dispatching in CLANG and GCC: https://johnnysswlab.com/cpu-dispatching-make-your-code-both-portable-and-fast/