# Why does the assembly use MOVUPS instruction for doubles?

Tags: c++, assembly, optimization, vectorization, sse

I have the following piece of code:

```
std::vector<double> a(1000000), b(1000000);  
// fill a with random doubles
for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); ++i) {  
    b[i] = a[i]*a[i] + a[i]; 
} 
std::cout << b[0] << std::endl; // make sure the compiler doesn't optimize the loop away
```

The generated assembly for the `for` loop (`g++ -O3`):

```
movupd  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR[rbp + 0 + rax]
movapd  xmm0, xmm1
mulpd   xmm0, xmm1
addpd   xmm0, xmm1
movups  XMMWORD PTR[r12 + rax], xmm0
add     rax, 16
cmp     rax, 8000000
jne.L17
```

I can comprehend the assembly up to the following line:

```
movups  XMMWORD PTR[r12 + rax], xmm0
```

Here the result of `a[i] * a[i] + a[i]`is written back to memory (in a vectorized fashion). But why is the `movups` (single precision) instruction invoked rather than `movupd` (double precision)?

Comment: Hmm. As far as I can tell, the *only* difference between `MOVUDP` and `MOVUPS` is that the former has a `0x66` prefix byte. Maybe the compiler has spotted a code alignment trick by using the non-prefixed instruction once and the prefixed one once?

Comment: ... so maybe the question should be why does it use `MOVUPD` in the first instance?

Comment: The compiler should prefer `movups` if possible as the encoding is shorter.  `movups` and `movupd` do the exact same thing.

Comment: Thank you guys for your replies. @fuz Could you please elaborate a little bit further? What do you by "encoding is shorter"?

Comment: @Urwald `movupd xmm, xmm/m` is `66 0F 10 /r` whereas `movups xmm, xmm/m` is just `0F 10 /r`.  I.e. the `66` prefix byte is absent, saving one byte of memory over `movupd`.

Comment: @Urwald Instructions are stored in memory/file as sequences of bytes (called opcodes). Your `movupd` takes 6 bytes, while `moveups` only 5. Live demo: https://shell-storm.org/online/Online-Assembler-and-Disassembler/?inst=movupd++xmm1%2C+XMMWORD+PTR%5Brbp+%2B+0+%2B+rax%5D%0D%0Amovups++XMMWORD+PTR%5Br12+%2B+rax%5D%2C+xmm0&arch=x86-64&as_format=inline#assembly.

Comment: [VEX prefixes encoding and SSE/AVX MOVUP(D/S) instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51773399) shows disassembly for movups vs. movupd.